# JpaRepository Distinct doesn't work with more than one field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, distinct

I have this query that works fine

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT taxonomyGroup FROM sagePrices AS sP WHERE sP.brand = :brand AND sP.taxonomyGroup IS NOT NULL", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findTaxonomyByBrandMatching(String brand);
```

But I want to use JPARepository. I tried several options already, but nothing really worked, I'm getting all the correct records, but they are still duplicated

These are the several options that I tried.

```
List<SagePricesEntity> findTaxonomyGroupDistinctByBrandAndTaxonomyGroupNotNull(String brand);
List<SagePricesEntity> findDistinctTaxonomyGroupByBrandAndTaxonomyGroupNotNull(String brand);
List<SagePricesEntity> findDistinctTaxonomyGroupByTaxonomyGroupNotNullAndBrand(String brand);
```

Does anyone knows if what I'm trying to do is possible?

This is the response that I get when using JPARepository queries

```
[
    {
        "taxonomyGroup": "rtrtr"
    },
    {
        "taxonomyGroup": "rtrtr"
    },
    {
        "taxonomyGroup": "fhfdhfdhdfh"
    },
    {
        "taxonomyGroup": "ydtyjtyjetyj"
    }
]
```

Comment: It will find distinct entities, w hich propably is all records. You are basically comparing apples and oranges as your SQL gets a single column, whereas the other gets a whole entity.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that this was possible somehow.

Comment: You would need a projection or specific query (could be JPQL) to work. It will do a distinct on the whole row and as the ids differ (I guess) this won't work as each row is distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use spring projection for get only one column value

```
 interface TaxonomyGroupOnly{
        String getTaxonomyGroup(); 
    }

List<TaxonomyGroupOnly> findDistinctTaxonomyGroupByBrandAndTaxonomyGroupNotNull(String category);
```

more about Spring Projection - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections